# Why does @font-face only work in localhost?

Tags: css, font-face

I used @font-face on my new site, it works fine in localhost in both FF and Chrome. However, when I upload it to my server, I can't see the fonts in FF or Chrome. What could be some possible causes?

My website is http://leojiang.me

Comment: what are you using to generate your "style.css"?

Comment: you have a rule `body, button, input, select, textarea` that is further down setting the font to `sans serif`

Comment: Don't write answers in questions.

Comment: @Shad: I wasn't talking to you; your comment is fine. The OP had edited a solution into his question, which I reverted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oops, =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shad found the problem: "you have a rule body, button, input, select, textarea that is further down setting the font to sans serif".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While debugging your site you may want to have an easier to read css script to help find some of the problems. Compression should only be done when everything works the way you intend it to.

for now you can copy/paste it on this site to see it more clearly:
http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/css-beautifier.html

I was a bit suspicious of the @media print and the later one for @page. I am not sure if those are set up properly. I would suggest concentrating on the website first by commenting out the print specifics to help you troubleshoot the web rendering problem. You may want to set up a test html page with all the various elements you wish to use and make sure they are working properly before incorporating the 3d shapes. Just make an html file and remove those classes so you can see how everything renders as a basic web page.

As Ettiene said, there are several spots where the code is setting the font for different elements to Lucida Grande and Courier. These locations are where you should be referencing your desired font name, ColThin. How you name them is important as well, check the file that was downloaded from font squirrel (if you got the font there). The html demo file that is included has some css which shows how to use the @font-face fonts:

```
p.style1 {font: 18px/27px 'ColaborateThinRegular', Arial, sans-serif;}
```

You are missing the quotation marks, so the css may not be registering the new font name. As well, setting it on html and having those other font names in the code afterwards replaces the html setting. The only name that is important is how you designate the @font-face name. You could designate it 'smashed-font' and if you reference it as 'smashed-font' it will reference the files you have designated as 'smashed-font'. 'ColThin' should be fine.

From what I can see, you have copied the font files into their correct place, but how you want to use them is not quite right.

Good use of Paul Hayes 3d experiment, BTW. http://www.paulrhayes.com/2009-07/animated-css3-cube-interface-using-3d-transforms/

Bear in mind it may not work properly on several kinds of browsers, so have a fallback of some kind for people who are not fortunate enough to have webkit browsers, or include the alternatives such as -moz and -o and a version of the css which does not include -webkit, just in case these transformations make it into the css3 specifications.

If this is intimidating, consider it a learning experience. Polishing these mistakes through your own work will make your services that much more valuable to your potential clients.

Answer (score 0):

Your font familly name may be wrong..
try this one

font-family: 'ColaborateThinRegular';

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontfacedemo/Colaborate
Look at the source code of the page.

Comment: Nice job for the 3d effect in your site.